FGC Character select Layout in REACT
I’m a beginner at React and have designed a custom FGC (Fighting Game Community) layout in Figma. I want to implement it as a React app. This is the design:Character Layout
What are some approaches i can start with ?
i was thinking maybe a grid layout.

You can use Tailwindcss. You can use the grid or flex structures that suit you. You can review in the document. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-basis

i know what tailwind and what it does, but i still dont know how to use it yet? im still in the early grind of react.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
